# SQL Server installation issue while installing Winforms Application

Tags: c#, winforms, installshield

[image]

I embedded SQL Server setup in Winforms InstallShield Limited edition in Custom Actions. SQL Server setup runs while installing my Winforms Application. But SQL Server gets halted while installing Here ( Install_msoledbsql_Cpu64_Action ).

Comment: did you checked the installation logs? are there any error messages? have you tried running the installation as an administrator?

Comment: Yes, I have run it as Administrator but the same issue occurring.

Comment: (01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: Running Action: Install_msoledbsql_Cpu64_Action
(01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: SetFeaturePropsModifyInstallAction for msoledbsql_Cpu64 
(01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: Sco: Attempting to create base registry key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, machine 
(01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey 
(01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: Sco: Attempting to open registry subkey SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
(01) 2020-03-27 11:04:05 Slp: Sco: Attempting to get registry value InstallDir
(01) 2020-03-27 11Slp: Checkpoint: PREINSTALL_MSOLEDBSQL_CPU64_ACTION

Comment: Isn't the sql server install file corrupt? what parameters are used in the installer template? can you log the verbose install output?